What is the meaning of "sharply" in "Jem looked up sharply"?
This context comes from the book "To Kill A Mocking Bird" by Harper Lee
"Jem’s ears reddened from Atticus’s compliment, but he looked up sharply when
he saw Atticus stepping back."

sharply adv
quickly and suddenly:

Inflation has risen/fallen sharply.
His health improved/deteriorated sharply this week.
The road bends sharply to the left.(Cambridge Dictionary)

sharp adj
Vigilant; alert:

kept a sharp lookout for shoplifters. (American Heritage®)
Did Jem look up at Atticus "abruptly" or "vigilantly"
?

Yes, abruptly. quickly and suddenly. Like the dictionary says.

I think it's both. They both make sense, and Harper Lee's writing style is a sophisticated blend of simple language at the surface level, with a lot going on underneath, so I would always tend to assume any clever subtleties are intended. But this is really Off Topic literary criticism. Of course, another way of looking at it is to simply say the two definitions are just two sides of the same coin, that are naturally both manifest in the cited context.

The basic meaning is "quickly" but the author has chosen to use "sharply", perhaps because it has a second meaning.
